# Filter parsed csv data with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, csv

I'm using this code to specify what data to take and how to add it into my `HTML`.

```
window.onload = (function(CMS) {
//parse your csv file
Papa.parse("LINK", {
    download: true,
    complete: function(results) {
      console.log(results);
        $.each(results.data.slice(1), // skip first row of CSV headings
            function(find, data) {
                var title = data[0];
                var link = data[4];
                var date = data[2];
                var type = data[3];
                $('ul.nflist').append($('<li>', {
                    html: '<a href="' + link + '">' + title + '</a> ' + ' ' + '<span class="category">' + type + '</span>'
                }));
            });
        //weird issue with an empty line.. just delete the last <li>
        $('ul.nflist li:last-child').remove();
        //Now that your data is clean and in its proper place you can begin to do the preety stuff like add images to corresponding categories
        //First hide the category tag...
        $(".category").hide();
        // Now lets search for categories and add images
        $('ul.nflist li:contains("sm")').prepend('<img src="http://www.jonar.com/portal/partner/img/sendemailo.png" />');
        $('ul.nflist li:contains("blog")').prepend('<img src="http://www.jonar.com/portal/partner/img/bello.png" />');
        $('ul.nflist li:contains("ann")').prepend('<img src="http://www.jonar.com/portal/partner/img/calendaro.png" />');
        $('ul.nflist li:contains("itp")').prepend('<img src="http://www.jonar.com/portal/partner/img/pluscircleo.png" />');
    }
});
```

});

The json file looks like this when the csv is parsed:

```
[
{
    "title": "Choice, Happiness and Spaghetti Sauce",
    "summary_text": "Delivering product variety: chunky spaghetti sauce, zesty pickles, or weak coffee? Gladwell explains how the root of happy customers is product variety.",
    "date": "30-Jan-13",
    "type": "sm",
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?id=380939405308665&story_fbid=298838986905013"
},
{
    "title": "Servoy Interviewed Us",
    "summary_text": "Servoy interviewed our managing director,Jon Ruby. Find out why we chose Servoy and learn about our development best practices.",
    "date": "4-Nov-14",
    "type": "itp",
    "link": "https://plus.google.com/+ServoyPlus/posts/aUL28cD2hfH"
},
{
    "title": "Come Together, Right Now: The Benefits of Cross-Functional Teams",
    "summary_text": "What do you get when you put an engineer, a doctor and a lawyer in one room? Find out how to create an environment to sustain cross-functional teams.",
    "date": "2-May-13",
    "type": "blog",
    "link": "http://www.jonar.com/jonarblog/come-together-right-now-the-benefits-of-cross-functional-teams/"
},
{
    "title": "What is ERP?",
    "summary_text": "The acronym, �ERP� is tossed around constantly, but what does it actually mean for your business?",
    "date": "25-Aug-11",
    "type": "sm",
    "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVRgIXLWDHs"
},
{
    "title": "Admit You Don�t Know � Take The Road Less Traveled",
    "summary_text": "If you�ve ever felt like a fraud, you�re not alone. Instead of ignoring it, here�s why you should embrace the experience of Imposter Syndrome.",
    "date": "17-Oct-14",
    "type": "blog",
    "link": "http://www.jonar.com/jonarblog/admit-you-dont-know-take-the-road-less-travelled/"
},
{
    "title": "Jonar is Looking to Build Our Network of VAP�s",
    "summary_text": "Jonar has started building an international network of partners. Want in? Join us on our journey to reinvent ERP.",
    "date": "no date",
    "type": "ann",
    "link": "http://www.jonar.com/new/signUp.html"
},
{
    "title": ""
}
```

]

Here is the issue there are types that have `sm`. I don't want these rows... Lets say the type `sm` it should not include the row.. How can i filter the data?

Comment: generically, `results.data.slice(1).filter(function(o){return o.type!="sm"; })`

Comment: hey @dandavis that unfortunately did not work.. That's my problem it should of been simple but i cant figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
       $.each(results.data.slice(1), // skip first row of CSV headings
              function(find, data) {
               if(data.type !="sm") { 
                   var title = data.title;
                   var link  = data.link;
                   var date  = data.date;
                   var type  = data.type;
               }
              }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Each element of the array is an object so you need to access the properties of that object:

Change :

```
 var title = data[0];
```

To:

```
 var title = data.title;
```

And do same for all other variables and properties

Comment: Last row isn't completing so best to check all those properties exist first...assuming data shown is accurate

Comment: hi @charliefl the last row contains a space thats the only problem i will delete that... although changing it to .title renders my data undefined

Comment: should work fine based on what is shown... here's a simple demo http://plnkr.co/edit/pG4D9uaV2D4CZEWIAXtT?p=preview

Comment: Hi @charliefl i just looked at your url it does not work it is giving every single row... `sm` is only in 2 rows...

Comment: I copied the `if`  too fast... working for only `sm` now. Point is there shouldn't be `undefined`